# Combine two TransposeToTxt, so they save to the same file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two different TransposeToTxt functions, that I can save individually using a FileDialog prompt, they are saved to a specific format. However I need to get them into the same file, so that the second one just follows the first one.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function fnTransposeToTxt()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fd As DAO.Field
    Dim fnum As Integer
    Dim path As String
    Dim OK As Boolean
    Dim var As Variant
    ' export to this file
    path = FilToSave
    
    fnum = FreeFile
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("VBK_Knude", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            
            OK = True
            
            Open path For Output As fnum
            
        End If
        Do Until .EOF
            For Each fd In .Fields
                var = fd.Value
                Select Case fd.Name
                    Case "AFLKOEF"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.0")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "XY", "TEXTXY", "Z_F", "DYBDE", "OB", "PERPEND", "Q", "STATION", "PERPEND", "AFSTRØM"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "DIMENSION"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.000")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "OPLAND"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.0000")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                End Select
                Print #fnum, fd.Name & " " & var
            Next
            .MoveNext
            If Not (.EOF) Then
                Print #fnum, ""
            End If
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    If OK Then
        Close #fnum
    
        MsgBox "table imported to " & path
    End If
End Function
```

Second function:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function fnTransposeToTxt()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fd As DAO.Field
    Dim fnum As Integer
    Dim path As String
    Dim OK As Boolean
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim foundXY As Boolean
    ' export to this file
    path = FilToSave
    
    fnum = FreeFile
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("VBK_Ledning", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            
            OK = True
            
            Open path For Output As fnum
            
        End If
        Do Until .EOF
            foundXY = False
            For Each fd In .Fields
                var = fd.Value
                Select Case fd.Name
                    Case "AFLKOEF", "FALD", "MANNING", "ACCU_Q"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.0")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "XY", "TEXTXY", "FRA_Z", "TIL_Z", "LÆNGDE", "PERPEND", "REDUKTION", "EXTRA_OB", "PERPEND", "AFSTRØM"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                        If fd.Name = "XY" Then
                            foundXY = True
                        End If
                    Case "DIMENSION"
                        var = Format$(var, "0")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "XY1"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                        If foundXY Then
                            Print #fnum, "XY " & var
                        Else
                            Print #fnum, "XY"
                            foundXY = True
                        End If
                End Select
                If fd.Name <> "XY1" Then
                    Print #fnum, fd.Name & " " & var
                End If
            Next
            .MoveNext
            If Not (.EOF) Then
                Print #fnum, ""
            End If
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    If OK Then
        Close #fnum
    
        MsgBox "table imported to " & path
    End If
End Function
```

I've tried a few different solutions, but keep either getting a File is Open error or BadName error with my tries:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function ExportToTxt()
    
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fd As DAO.Field
    Dim fnum As Integer
    Dim path As String
    Dim OK As Boolean
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim foundXY As Boolean
    Dim ff As Long
    
    ' export to this file
    path = FilToSave
    
    fnum = FreeFile
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    
    ' open recordset for table VBK_Knude
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("VBK_Knude", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            OK = True
            Open path For Output As fnum
            Do Until .EOF
                For Each fd In .Fields
                    var = fd.Value
                    Select Case fd.Name
                        Case "AFLKOEF"
                            var = Format$(var, "0.0")
                            var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                        Case "XY", "TEXTXY", "Z_F", "DYBDE", "OB", "PERPEND", "Q", "STATION", "AFSTRØM" ' Removed duplicate "PERPEND" case
                            var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                            var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                        Case "DIMENSION"
                            var = Format$(var, "0.000")
                            var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                        Case "OPLAND"
                            var = Format$(var, "0.0000")
                            var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    End Select
                    Print #fnum, fd.Name & " " & var
                Next
                .MoveNext
                If Not (.EOF) Then
                    Print #fnum, ""
                End If
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With
   
    ' open recordset for table VBK_Ledning
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("VBK_Ledning", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            
            OK = True
            
            ' check if file is already open
            ff = FreeFile
            On Error Resume Next
            Open path For Append Access Write Lock Write As #ff
            If Err.Number = 70 Then ' file is already open
                Close #ff
                OK = False
                MsgBox "File " & path & " is already open. Please close the file and try again."
                Exit Function
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            ' append to file opened earlier
            
            Do Until .EOF
                foundXY = False
                For Each fd In .Fields
                    var = fd.Value
                    Select Case fd.Name
                        Case "AFLKOEF", "FALD", "MANNING", "ACCU_Q"
                            var = Format$(var, "0.0")
                            var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                        Case "XY", "TEXTXY", "FRA_Z", "TIL_Z", "LÆNGDE", "PERPEND", "REDUKTION", "EXTRA_OB", "AFSTRØM" ' Removed duplicate "PERPEND" case
                            var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                            var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                            If fd.Name = "XY" Then
                                foundXY = True
                            End If
                Case "DIMENSION"
                    var = Format$(var, "0")
                    var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                Case "XY1"
                    var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                    var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    If foundXY Then
                        Print #fnum, "XY " & var
                    Else
                        Print #fnum, "XY"
                        foundXY = True
                    End If ' Add this line
            End Select
            
            If fd.Name <> "XY1" Then
                Print #fnum, fd.Name & " " & var
            End If
            Next
            .MoveNext
            If Not (.EOF) Then
                Print #fnum, ""
            End If
            ' close the file before opening it again
            Close #fnum
            Loop
        End If
        .Close
    End With
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    
    If OK Then
        Close #fnum
    
        MsgBox "table imported to " & path
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just excluding the first closure of the file to leave it open, and then continue with the second recordset:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function fnTransposeToTxt()

    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fd As DAO.Field
    Dim fnum As Integer
    Dim path As String
    Dim OK As Boolean
    Dim var As Variant
    ' export to this file
    path = FilToSave
    
    fnum = FreeFile
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("VBK_Knude", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            OK = True
            Open path For Output As fnum
        End If
        
        Do Until .EOF
            For Each fd In .Fields
                var = fd.Value
                Select Case fd.Name
                    Case "AFLKOEF"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.0")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "XY", "TEXTXY", "Z_F", "DYBDE", "OB", "PERPEND", "Q", "STATION", "PERPEND", "AFSTRØM"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "DIMENSION"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.000")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "OPLAND"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.0000")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                End Select
                Print #fnum, fd.Name & " " & var
            Next
            .MoveNext
            If Not (.EOF) Then
                Print #fnum, ""
            End If
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("VBK_Ledning", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    
    With rst
        If Not (.BOF And .EOF) Then
            .MoveFirst
            OK = True
        End If
        Do Until .EOF
            foundXY = False
            For Each fd In .Fields
                var = fd.Value
                Select Case fd.Name
                    Case "AFLKOEF", "FALD", "MANNING", "ACCU_Q"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.0")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "XY", "TEXTXY", "FRA_Z", "TIL_Z", "LÆNGDE", "PERPEND", "REDUKTION", "EXTRA_OB", "PERPEND", "AFSTRØM"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                        If fd.Name = "XY" Then
                            foundXY = True
                        End If
                    Case "DIMENSION"
                        var = Format$(var, "0")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                    Case "XY1"
                        var = Format$(var, "0.00")
                        var = Replace(var, ",", ".")
                        If foundXY Then
                            Print #fnum, "XY " & var
                        Else
                            Print #fnum, "XY"
                            foundXY = True
                        End If
                End Select
                If fd.Name <> "XY1" Then
                    Print #fnum, fd.Name & " " & var
                End If
            Next
            .MoveNext
            If Not (.EOF) Then
                Print #fnum, ""
            End If
        Loop
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    
    If OK Then
        Close #fnum
        MsgBox "table imported to " & path
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Well, when you put it like that it seemed obvious. I tried a few times, but apparently didn't get it right. Yours work perfectly. Just added a Print #fnum, "" between the two exports. Appreciate the help.